# Send UDP data to all on the LAN Android

Tags: java, android, network-programming, udp

I am able to send UDP data to a specific ip address but I need to send it to who ever is listening on port 55555. here is the code I'm using. I do not want to send to a specific ip.

```
import android.util.Log;

import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;

public class UdpServer implements Runnable {

    UdpServer() {
        run();
    }
    public void run() {

        try {

            String messageStr = "40320";

            int server_port = 55555;
            DatagramSocket datagramSocket = new DatagramSocket();
            InetAddress host = InetAddress.getByName("10.1.10.14");

            int msg_length = messageStr.length();
            byte[] message = messageStr.getBytes();
            DatagramPacket datagramPacket = new DatagramPacket(message, msg_length,host,
                    server_port);

            datagramSocket.send(datagramPacket);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to send a broadcast packet?

Comment: Your application should be work like Server. not a Client. So its just like, you have to send data packet on your own IP and port, so whichever client will listen to your app on your device IP and Port will receive those packets.

Comment: Yes @light this is as far as i can get with that  datagramSocket.setBroadcast(true); i need some more info on how to make that work. I was reading about multicast but unsure how to implement that or what the real differences are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Broadcasting will send data to all devices on the LAN.  Multicasting will only send data only to those who subscribe to it.  From the limited information you gave, it sounds like multicasting would work.  If you broadcast, you will essentially be sending data to all devices on your lan like your smart tv, all laptops, etc.

Here is a simple client server app using java multicast sockets.http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/net/multicastsocket-net/java-net-multicastsocket-example/

With multicasting, a device acts as a server and opens a special kind of udp socket for multicasting.  Clients subscribe to this server's multicast socket and essentially participate in data transmission.

Here are a couple tips for multicasting

- Be sure the server uses a multicast address in your java code.  This is in the range of 224.0.0.0 - 239.255.255.255   Some addresses are reserved.  Sample code I sent uses 224.0.0.3.  You don't need to change the IP in the WIfi settings.  This is done in the java code.  It is like an extra address that it will listen on.   The clients will subscribe to this address.
- For android, you will have to enable multicasting permission in the manifest file for the multicast lock.  See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.MulticastLock.html

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response.  That clarifies how java/droid does multicasting. The special listening address you mention is the missing link for me. What about security do you believe this would be blocked in most LAN?

Comment: It is possible but generally multicast is not blocked on unless you enable some special rule in your router.

Answer (score 0):

MainActivity.java

```
    package com.example.myapplication;
    
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.StrictMode;
    import android.util.Log;
    
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.net.DatagramPacket;
    import java.net.DatagramSocket;
    import java.net.InetAddress;
    import java.net.UnknownHostException;
    
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
        final static String INET_ADDR = "192.168.17.20";
        final static int PORT = 4210;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
            // StrictMode
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    
            // UDP Socket Programming
            // Get the address that we are going to connect to.
            InetAddress addr = null;
            try {
                addr = InetAddress.getByName(INET_ADDR);
            } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
                Log.i("ERROR", String.valueOf(ex));
            }
    
            // Open a new DatagramSocket, which will be used to send the data.
            try (DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket()) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    String msg = "Sent message no " + i;
    
                    // Create a packet that will contain the data
                    // (in the form of bytes) and send it.
                    DatagramPacket msgPacket = new DatagramPacket(msg.getBytes(),
                            msg.getBytes().length, addr, PORT);
                    try {
                        serverSocket.send(msgPacket);
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex){
                        Log.i("ERROR", String.valueOf(ex));
                    }
    
                    Log.i("DEBUG", "Server sent packet with msg: " + msg);
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Log.i("ERROR", String.valueOf(ex));
            }
        }
    }
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```